# Display inherited content in a page that is placed in a folder doesn't work

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3 (6.0) and have a problem with displaying inherited content elements. I have set up the template with the slide variable:

```
temp.content = CONTENT
temp.content {
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.where = colPos = 0
  select.languageField = sys_language_uid
}

temp.content_slide = CONTENT
temp.content_slide {
  table = tt_content
  select.orderBy = sorting
  select.languageField = sys_language_uid
  slide = -1
}
```

This works pretty well for the pages that are below the main page, AS LONG as they are not contained in a folder. When the subpages are contained in a folder, all inherited content elements are NOT SHOWN.

So:
MainPage > StandardSite1 > StandardSite2

> > All inherited elements from MainPage are shown in the StandardSites

MainPage > Folder > StandardSite3

> > NO inherited element from MainPage is shown in StandardSite3

Any idea, how to show the inherited content elements of MainPage in Standard sites, that are contained in a folder?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible, because you slide up the rootline to collect the content elements. However the rootline breaks at a storage folder.